# how to restrict data loadin in tabs while clicking in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 2 tabs in my application and i am getting all datas in API response. So at first time itself my all datas are getting loaded.

My two tabs are

- tab 1
- tab 2

So by default always it is in tab 1. So I want to load only tab 1 data and i do not want to load tab 2 datas. After click on tab 2 only i need to load the tab 2 datas and that time i don't want to load the tab 1 datas.

- I have a flag called "isfirst". If "isfirst" is "1", then i need to load only the first tab content. Same as if "isfirst" is "0", then i need to load only the second tab content.
- It is for performance improvement. If I click on second tab, the first tab existing data should not get load again. and if i click first tab again i need to destroy the second tab datas.

Please look at the plunkr,

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Ng9PHkrluKUSzQhor34?p=preview&preview)

```js
[
 {
 "fruit":[
  {"Apple":"Apple content goes here", "isfirst":"1"},
  {"Pear":"Pear content goes here", "isfirst":"0"}
]
}
   ]
```

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var TabsDemoCtrl = function ($scope,$http, $timeout) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:"Apple", content:[] , isLoaded:false , active:true},
    {  title:"Pear", content:[] , isLoaded:false }
  ];
  
  

  
  $scope.getContent=function(index){
    /* see if we have data already */
    if($scope.tabs.isLoaded){
      return
    }
    /* or make request for data delayed to show Loading... */
    $timeout(function(){
        var jsonFile='data1.json'
            $http.get(jsonFile).then(function(res){
            $scope.tabs.content=res.data[0].fruit;
            console.log(res.data[0].fruit);
            $scope.tabs.isLoaded=true;
        });
    
    },100)
  
  }
  
  
  
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
  

  <tabset>
   
    
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" select="getContent($index)" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
  <div ng-hide="!tabs.isLoaded">
  <h1>{{tab.title}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="item in tabs.content">
      <p>{{item[tab.title]}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="tabs.isLoaded"><h3>Loading...</h3></div>
  </tab>
    
    
  </tabset>

  <hr />

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here how to restrict loading datas using angularjs. Based on the tab click i want to load the datas dynamically.

Comment: You seem to have only one data file. So please could you elaborate what do you mean by loading the data dynamically for each tab. Does each tab need to fetch diifferent json file for the data, if yes then how will each tab know about what json file to fetch?

Comment: @amrendersingh I have a flag called "isfirst". If "isfirst" : "1" means first tab. else second tab. each tab need to fetch same json file based on flag.